# IIS Express Url Rewrite with 2 params don't work

Tags: web-config, iis-express, iis-8

Simply I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="index/page/method to index.php?page=page&method=method">
                <match url="^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page={R:1}&method={R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="index/page to index.php?page=page">
                <match url="^index/([^/]+)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page={R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="index to index.php">
                <match url="^index" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
     </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I call localhost I get the following:
HTTP-Fehler 500.19 - Internal Server Error

My problem is the first rule doesn't work :(
The rules work fine as I delete the first rule...
Can someone help me?

**Edit by myself:
IIS doesn't like the &...so I changed it to `&amp;` and it works fine^^**

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that you shoud use `&amp;`, as Microsoft says so in its article,

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module